# Each time I run Selenium to ping a specific site, my WebDriver ends up going to a completely different URL

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to go to this site: https://www.pluginillinois.org/offers.aspx?said=2

Each time I have some code that looks like the following:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import pyautogui


driverpath = r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe"
browserProfile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browserProfile.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath, options=browserProfile)
browser.get('https://www.pluginillinois.org/offers.aspx?said=2')
```

My Selenium browser will open and go to a completely different URL instead. The browser will instead go to https://www.pluginillinois.org/OffersBegin.aspx.

Is there a way to obfuscate this behavior?

Comment: I have the same URL (https://www.pluginillinois.org/OffersBegin.aspx) when I try to open the link (it's redirected on web site (I tried with a real browser (Chrome)) -- so, the problem is not related to Selenium). It's implemented in such a way.

Comment: The server is deliberately sending you somewhere else.  Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: well. shoot. thank you. I'll see if I can find a workaround.